# How does vim display its content

Tags: python, vim, terminal, editor

I'm struggling to find on the internet how editors like `vim`, `nano` or `emacs` display its content. By using the `subprocess` module of python, I have found there is nothing written to `stdout` or `stderr` by `vim`. So how does vim display its content? Also, is it even possible to capture the output by an editor like `vim` with a python script?

(I'm only asking about the concept, not to write the program for me.)

**EDIT:**

To give more context about my question, I'm trying to operate `vim` by using `python3.7`'s `subprocess` module, meaning I have read access to `STDOUT` and `STDERR` streams and write access to `STDIN` stream bound to `vim`.

`vim` is just an example here, it could be programs like `nano` or `less` or `emacs` etc.

Comment: vim is using [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses)

Comment: So is it possible, say, to operate vim by piping things into STDIN?

Comment: @pkqxdd you can "pip" in vim commands like so `vim +'Ex command1 | Ex command2 | ...' file`

Comment: @modesitt Thanks, that was a useful piece of information. I actually meant to "pipe", not "pip" by the way.

Comment: @pkqxdd hahah I meant pipe too, just put in quotes because it is not pipeing

Comment: What kind of `vim` commands do you want to run? The basic commands are (intentionally) identical to the ones in `ed`, which has a simple command line interface instead of a curses visual one. And then there’s `sed`, which also copies the most useful commands from `ed` but is written specifically to be a tool driven by other programs instead of an interactive editor. If you’re trying to run some command out of a vim plugin or make vim do some animation by moving the cursor around key by key, that won’t help, but for a lot of things, driving sed or ed works, and is easier than driving vim.

Comment: More generally: most curses apps write to the /dev/tty or some platform equivalent instead of writing to stdout or stderr, which means the only way you can intercept it is just creating a pty, making sure it’s configured to fool them into thinking it has the same term caps as the real tty, and handing them that. At which point you will capture all the crazy terminal strings for moving the cursor around and so on, which you’ll have to interpret yourself. (You may even need to respond properly to some.) Certainly doable, but not trivial.

Comment: Some full-screen tools can also work in a minimal or non-interactive mode where they write to stdout when given a non-functional terminal. For example, IIRC, less will act like more, with a limited command set and no fancy screen redrawing, just dumping 23 lines at a time, and that’s a lot easier to drive.

Comment: most of the comments are inaccurate :-(